# JavaScript Node js `res.send is not a function error`

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var q = url_parts.query;
  console.log(q.query);

   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));

console.log(q.query);
}).listen(8080);
```

Using this code I'm able to receive request, but I'm unable to respond to it. It shows `TypeError: res.send is not a function`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to do `res.end` instead of `res.send`. `res.send` is a part of `express` module and not of core `http module`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasted 5 hours on this :(